# Inferred, static and dynamic types of nested optionals and their arrays in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, option-type, dynamictype

There appear to be inconsistencies between inferred and dynamic types of values in the following code (beyond the expected generality on the static side):

```
                            // playground values in Xcode 7.0.1 (7A1001)
                            // (same behaviour in a release build)

let oi: Int?   = nil        // nil
let ooi: Int?? = nil        // nil

let os          = [oi, ooi] // [{nil}, nil]
let anys: [Any] = [oi, ooi] // [nil, nil]

oi  == nil                  // true
ooi == nil                  // true

os[0] == nil                // false
os[1] == nil                // true

os[0].dynamicType           // Optional<Optional<Int>>.Type
os[1].dynamicType           // Optional<Optional<Int>>.Type

anys[0].dynamicType         // Optional<Int>.Type
anys[1].dynamicType         // Optional<Optional<Int>>.Type

(os[0] as Any).dynamicType  // Optional<Optional<Int>>.Type
(os[1] as Any).dynamicType  // Optional<Optional<Int>>.Type

os[0]!                      // nil
os[1]!                      // fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

For example, should we not expect `os[0].dynamicType` to return `Optional<Int>.Type`?

Answer (score 0):

When you see `let os = [oi, ooi] // [{nil}, nil]`, the curly braces are important because they say that the first item of the array has indeed a value and this value is nil (it may sound weird, I know).

If you do `os.dynamicType`, you'll get `Array<Optional<Optional<Int>>>.Type`.

It can be even more clear with the following code:

```
switch os[0]
{
case .None: print("None")
case .Some(let value): print("Some")        // "Some\n"
    switch value
    {
    case .None: print("None")               // "None\n"
    case .Some(let value): print("Some")
    }
}
```

That's also why `os[0]!` equals to `nil` and doesn't crash.

In my opinion, it's easier to think about optionals as `Struct` when you deal with multiple optional layers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Alas, I'm not quite sure what is made "more clear" by your code example. Note that nested optionals are pattern-matched flat (e.g. switching over `ooi` of type `Int??` would print `None` by that same code). So whether `os[0]` is pattern-matched as an `Int?` or an `Int??`, the behaviour should not be as observed...